# is there a way to write these python codes for a transaction created, having a constructor? i get a syntax error with these

Tags: python, solidity, web3py

```
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor{}.buildTransaction(
    ("chainId": chain_id, "from": my_address, "nonce": nonce)
    )
print(transaction)
```

Comment: You need to show the error (and read it, since it should tell you exactly what and where your error is) in your question, as well.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct syntax for `web3.py`:

```py
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction({
    'chainId': chain_id,
    'from': my_address,
    'nonce': nonce
})
```

However by using [brownie](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#) you can manage, test and deploy smart contracts in more comfortable way than `web3.py`